# How can I play a full screen video across multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Is it possible to play a full screen video across nine screens?

I want this for my chain of shops to display my video on a big display. The video will be played on a player such as VLC.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?  Are you trying to mirror the image on 9 screens?  Or have one image be spanned across 9 screens?  Also, you imply these screens are in different shops, how far away are they?

Comment: Each shop will have 9 screens. On the 9 screens I want to play video expanded to the whole area. Just like turning it into one huge screen

Comment: So long as your video card is up to the task. The main issue isn't nine screens really, it is the number of pixels those nine screens represent. So long as you've arranged the windows correctly (if you're using Windows) you can drag a video player window to cover all of the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  The easiest method would probably be to simply get a Desktop PC and put multiple graphics cards in.  For example the AMD FirePro W600 supports 6 displays.  With 2 of these cards you could handle 12 displays.  Once everything is hooked up you can simply arrange the displays using Windows/Linux.  You'll need to make sure the PC has enough power and space to accommodate the extra graphics cards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have desktop with 2 graphics card. I have 9 tv screens as monitors. Will I need to get special splitter to connect tv screens to desktop?

Comment: That depends on what kind of graphics cards you have.  If you have the W300 I mentioned above it has 6 ports/card.  So no splitter required, just lots of long cables.  Keep in mind that most graphics cards can only support 2-4 monitors, so make sure you read the details before buying one.

Comment: Ah I see that now thanks for your help. One last question, do I need any special software to make it display out over the 9 screens?

Comment: Probably not, software exists that might make it easier to manage, or easier to configure, but none of it is necessarily required.